# Animated GIF as texture in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, textures, gif

I'm looking for a way to use a GIF animation as texture in THREE.js. I am currently able to load a texture (even GIF format), but it doesn't play its animation.

Is there any way to do it? I found some links like these:

https://github.com/JordiRos/GLGif

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

But I need to play GIF animation as a texture, not in a Canvas.

Comment: You say "I need to play GIF animation as a texture, not in a Canvas" but Three.js textures are rendered to a canvas.

Comment: What do you mean "not in a Canvas"?

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing isn't an animated GIF as a texture. The sites you linked use libraries to render each individual frame of the GIF as a texture and then cycle through them by changing the offset of the textured image.

Look at the source for the `TextureAnimation` link and see line 157. That is the object that performs this. You can see that the running animation isn't a GIF at all:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/images/run.png

Answer (score 4):

I had a similiar issue with animations using threejs. 
So I created a simple package to solve that:
https://github.com/MaciejWWojcik/three-plain-animator

I hope that will help someone who get here for answers about threejs animations.

Comment: the example from stemkoski was very helpful for creating this

Comment: Gif files are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Use [gifuct-js](http://matt-way.github.io/gifuct-js/) to render a gif into a Canvas and then use [CanvasTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture) with that canvas as a source.

Here's my POC that seems to work(may need refreshing the preview after it loads)
https://codesandbox.io/s/giftexture-51rmw

Answer (score 2):

Create a video element, load that element using VideoTexture and add the texture to your mesh.

```
// Create video and play
let textureVid = document.createElement("video")
textureVid.src = `texture.mp4`; // transform gif to mp4
textureVid.loop = true;
textureVid.play();


// Load video texture
let videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(textureVid);
videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
videoTexture.maxFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
videoTexture.generateMipmaps = false;

// Create mesh
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: videoTexture } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add(mesh);
```

Comment: Thanks, this allowed me to have a cloud animation video on my Earth sphere. I had to add `textureVid.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';` and use `textureVid.src = 'http://localhost:8080/texture.mp4';` to have locally served files in the element, `textureVid.muted = true;` to have the element working in the first place, and `videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBAFormat;` since it seems that the RGBFormat was removed from Three.js recently.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using an animated GIF as texture could be to use a tool such as ffmpeg to convert the animated gif into a video file, and then use that video as a texture, which is supported by WebGL.