# How to display GIF textures in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, gif

I have a gif file that I want to use as an image texture in three.js. Right now, it loads as a still image when I would like the gif animation to render. Is there any way to do this? I know that A-Frame has a custom shader for gif textures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated GIF as texture in THREE.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21710049/animated-gif-as-texture-in-three-js)

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate. Unfortunately, the duplicate has no answers either, but that is because there isn't an easy solution. There is technically no way for javascript code to access the individual frames of an animated .GIF, so there is no straightforward way to implement this in three.js . A workaround (preprocessing the gif to multiple images / one big image with offsets, either offline or server-side) seems most practical.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this option: https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

He basically has a long png that changes it's position.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with animations using threejs. So I created a simple package to solve that: https://github.com/MaciejWWojcik/three-plain-animator

I hope that will help someone who gets here for answers about threejs animations.

Of course, the stemkowski example was very helpful for creating this